# Recursion output C

Tags: c, recursion, output

I have a question with the output of this recursion

```
void recursiveFunction(int num) {
    if (num < 3) {
        recursiveFunction(num + 1);
        printf("%d\n", num);
        recursiveFunction(num + 1); 
    }
}
int main() {
    recursiveFunction(0);
};
```

Output:

```
2 1 2 0 2 1 2
```

I know what recursion is in theory. 
I also get it until the `num` is 3, it goes out of the function but I don't get why it prints 2 instead of 3. Why does it subtract with 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain why you expect an output of 3 and how the printf can be reached with `num` being 3.

Comment: How could it ever print out '3'?  No matter what the call stack, it is not possible to get to the printf if num=3.  Please explain more...

Comment: So when num reach 3 it goes out of the function :  if (3<3){}. Then it goes to the printf , and is num still 3? I don't see how it goes from 3 to 2.

Comment: 'Then it goes to the printf'... yes, with num=2.  The call with parameter num of 3 returned without printing anything, just as you have coded it.

Comment: Step through it with your debugger and check the value/s of num at each step, all will be revealed.

Comment: Step through it with your _head_ and all will be revealed. If you want to be a programmer you must be able to solve this in your head, without using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

It will look something like this:

```
f(0)
    0 < 3 yes
        f(1)
            1 < 3 yes
                f(2)
                    2 < 3 yes
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                        print(2)
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                print(1)
                f(2)
                    2 < 3 yes
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                        print(2)
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
        print(0)
        f(1)
            1 < 3 yes
                f(2)
                    2 < 3 yes
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                        print(2)
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                print(1)
                f(2)
                    2 < 3 yes
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
                        print(2)
                        f(3)
                            3 < 3 no
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of 3 will never be printed due to the if condition. Maybe this code will help you to understand it better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recursiveFunction(int num) {
    if (num < 3) {
        recursiveFunction(num + 1); /* recursive call*/
        printf("[inside if statement] num = %d\n", num);
    }

    /*Here num will be equal to 3 */
    printf("num = %d\n", num);

    return;
}

int main() {
    recursiveFunction(0);

    return (0);
}
```